# What is the ruling of touching the logos (slogan) which have Allah's names? (Shia view)

Tags: sharia, shiism, wudu

As you can see, there are some logos (slogans) of the word Allah on many things such as flags. For instance there is a slogan of it on the flag of Islamic republic of Iran. I wonder if it is Halal if we touch it without Wudhu (the ablution which is before the prayer or for doing some Mustahab (recommended) acts))?

*Note: I am looking for Shia view*

Answer (score 1):

According to Grand Ayatullah Khamenei (آیه الله خامنئی):

> In accordance with the precaution (الاحتیاط) it is better that you
>   observe the rulings  ( احکام) which are related to the word “Allah” as
>   well.

Since according to the view of many Shiite Maraje’-al-Taqlid, it is considered as a Haram/forbidden act if you touch the names of Allah without Wudu. So, you’d better to observe it for other things such as the logo of the flags as well.

---

**Reference:**

- [www.hawzah.net](http://www.hawzah.net/fa/magazine/magart/2689/4284/27645)